# Reinstalling node.js is throwing error

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, nvm

I had node 6 before but I had to remove it to downgrade it to Node 4. But when I am trying to reinstall node 6/ install node 4, I am getting this error.

```
[root@vvvvvv xxxxxxx]# yum install -y nodejs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package 2:nodejs-6.11.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/414531) to remove the previous version.

after this, as per another website source, I tried

```
sudo rm -fv /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*
```

but to no avail!!

When I am checking `$node --version` or `$npm --version`, I dont get any valid output.

Comment: `yum uninstall nodejs` didn't work to remove Node.js? The answer you linked in your question is related to uninstalling on OS X

Comment: @AndrewLively yeah i read on other websites too, it was the same for Linux(Cent OS in my case). yum uninstall works only for the packages installed using yum. I didnt install nodejs using yum

Comment: How did you install nodejs? Did you install it from source? Because in your first code example you are trying to install using `yum`. And what do you mean by "valid output" when calling `node --version`?

Comment: @AndrewLively : turns out, `yum erase nodejs` helped me remove the nodejs-6.11.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64. Thanks for that.
Now incase I want to install node js 4, what is the way forward?

I did 
`curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -`
followed by 
`yum -y install nodejs`

but it fails giving the error 
`https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-6.11.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`

Comment: The `setup_4` might not be available anymore, I would use the latest version and then see my answer below to change the version of Node once it is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Node.js I would recommend using your package manager (yum):

```
yum install -y nodejs
```

Once you have nodejs and npm installed successfully on your machine, I would then use a Node version manager (I personally use [n](https://github.com/tj/n), but [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) works as well) to install a specific version:

```
npm install -g n
```

Then use your Node version manager to install a specific Node version:

```
n 4
```

NOTE: This command above will install the latest version of Node.js 4 (which at this time is 4.8.3). If you need a specific version you can specify it instead of just `n 4`. To see all available versions you can use the `n ls` command

You can verify your version of Node and npm using the `--version` flags as you were doing before

Comment: using `n` is giving me `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n’: Read-only file system` which I understand will be an issue of the access and I can not go past it.
I used nvm, and installed node 4.6.2. doing a `which node` gives me `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.2/bin/node` and `which npm` gives me `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.2/bin/npm`
But when I am in another terminal, i get error, `-ksh: node: not found`. Path issue?

Comment: In my experience the `read-only file system` issue is something bigger related to your machine and not to Node. Usually when I have got that it is because of a panic with the system which locked up the file system and I fixed with a system restart. If you have a path issue you could create an alias in `/usr/bin` for node and npm to the `nvm` installed path